# How can I make my Qt app see the "platforms" in a different place?

Tags: qt, plugins

I'm aware that, when installing a Qt application somewhere, I need to deploy the plugin related to the system being used in the folder `platforms`.

Traditionally this folder is supposed to be located in the same place where the executable is located. Well I want to change that: I want to put that folder one level back, that is, in place `../platforms`. **How can I tell my app to look in that place for the shared library?**

Reading some threads on the web I came to two possible solutions: one would be to use `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()`, but that is for "general plugins" (those that should be placed inside a `plugins` directory), not for the platform plugin AFAIK. Such this is that I tried this solution by adding "../" in the call to `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()`and it didn't work. (Should I have put "../platforms" instead?) The other solution seems to be by using `qt.conf`. The problem is that I don't know how to edit that file when it comes to adding a path to the platform plugin: [Digia's manual file](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) doesn't tell how to do this specific configuration.

Comment: qt.conf can configure the path for plugins as you said, and the documentation doesn't give any reason to think platform plugins are excluded. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @HamishMoffatt I tried it, it just didn't work :) How am I supposed to edit the file as to do that? I wrote: `Plugins = ../sqldrivers/;../platforms/` and it failed to search in those paths.

Comment: The doco suggests you should be setting Plugins to the top of the plugins tree (ie ..), not listing all the subdirectories. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

Comment: @HamishMoffatt it worked! :) Write your comments as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Plugins in qt.conf to point to the location of all the plugin sub-directories (ie .. in your example), rather than listing individual plugin sub-directories.